# Using Android-x86 on virtualbox

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-x86

I'm trying to start Android on Virtual box but whenever I start the VM the window remains on detecting android-x86 (with lots of dots).

I think the problem is that Virtualbox does not recognize the hdd because in the session info HDD's Data Read is 0 B. Does anyone know how I can I get VM's HDD detected for Android-x

Any help solving this problem would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I also used VMware. same problem there.